# Wowza : Live stream detected but does not play

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

This is the command I use to being the stream on my hardware device
*ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f rtsp rtsp://[user]:[password]@52.66.64.136:1935/test/myStream*

I can see that there is an input coming in from the Incoming Streams section of the Wowza Engine Manager.
The IP, Stream name & Application name are correct.
[image: Wowza Engine Manager]

However when I try to play the stream using the Test Players, I dont see anything. Just a black screen.
An error message at the bottom of Adobe HDS says Source stream or file could not be found or access was denied.

[image: Wowza Test Player]

When I try to use the RTSP wowza link on VLC I get an error stating that the "Input Cannot Be opened"

Source security for RTSP has been set to open.

When I stream through the GoCoder App there are no issues.
This leads me to believe the server is functioning correctly.

When I use the same command but change the output to write to file (*ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 out.mp4*) it works perfectly fine!!
So even the base command is correct.

Am I missing some arguments from the FFMPEG command?
Do I need to provide the username & password even though RTSP Source Security has been set to open?

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: @aergistal:  These are error logs from Wowza  
**WARN server comment 2016-09-02 15:15:37 - - - - - 99425.642 - - - - - - - - CupertinoPacketHandler.handleHolder[test/_definst_/myStream]: Invalid video codec for iPhone/iPod: MPEG4**

Comment: @aergistal : The camera hardware runs on OpenWRT, so I guess a few codecs are missing. 
However since I am able to write to a file without issues, I am guessing I should be able to stream too.

Comment: Does it work if you use [MPEG-TS](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?213-How-to-use-FFmpeg-with-Wowza-Media-Server-\(MPEG-TS\))?

Comment: @aergistal: No. MPEG-TS also does not seem to work. This is the command I am using `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f mpegts udp://52.66.64.136:10000/test/myStream?pkt_size=1316`